# Devise Cron Job Per User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to scan my Users database that Devise creates, in a Cron job and then repeat the fron job for every user.

So for example

I am wanting to run a cron job, to get all user ID's, then on each user ID run a certain command, for example pull email addresses and then output them in another DB.

I've been trying for a couple of days now with no Luck... and search all over the net to find an answer or something i can use and adapt.. can anyone spread any light on my problem...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with help from @Unixmonkey problem was the missing

```
".map(&:uid)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# lib/tasks/cron.rake
namespace :cron do
  desc 'gather users and send commands to cron'
  task :users => :environment do
    User.all.each do |user|
      `command to output in another db #{user.email}`
    end
  end
end

# crontab
0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /your/rails/dir && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake cron:users'
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a little, but I have anothing Issue, I am wanting to do the following..

find_all_by_provider('facebook')

Then, also look in the column UID. and get the UID for each user that has a provider facebook, If I do it with the command "find_by_provider('facebook') and then screen_name = uid it works, but when find_all_by.... it won't / doesn't understand the UID part...

Comment: screen_names = User.find_all_by_provider('facebook').map(&:uid)